# web service which provides stock market information

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am checking if there are any web services out there, to which I can post a ticker symbol and it will return me details about the symbol. Like if I pass 'GOOG' it will tell me that company name, the current price, whether its a Mutual Fund, Equity etc...

I am trying to make a PHP PoC for a service that can collate and show financial stock market information.

Any free service that anyone know of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had experience with a few of these service providers.
My favourite is the Yahoo Finance CSV API.

It returns formatted data based on the URL parameters you provide.

So for example you can post the following: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG to get financial information for the 'GOOG' ticker symbol.

Quick example from Yahoo: http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvQuotesDownload

Also check out this page for all the examples of data you can fetch: http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/, examples include:

Ask, Dividend Yield, Dividend per share, Ask, Previous Close, Open Date, Change and about 100 more.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That really looks promising. Do you know if it shows Security type for symbol? (whether symbol is Mutual fund or Equity). That is kind of the most important datapoint I want. I didnt see it there, but in any case it looks pretty neat! +1

Comment: @open_sourse I believe you're looking for Company CSV info. Yahoo have some documentation here: http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvCompanyDownload. If this helped you, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I use this other one. Very simple and effective

http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote?symbol=googl

Abd "symbol=googl" it is where you will say the ticker of the company